# Enterprise Architect Track Changes

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am using Enterprise Architect and want to be able to check the changes I have made prior to committing changes to version control.

I suspect that because of Enterprise Architects use of xml files to represent the model this is a little tricky, but is there anyway for me to view the specific changes I have made (i.e. diagrams I have added, requirements I have modified?)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EA's Version Control functionality does not support this. As you've noted, what actually gets stored in the version control system are XMI files, and XMI is a proprietary-extension format, which means third-party tools won't be able to make much sense of the changes between two versions.

What you can do is use EA's Baselines, which do include the ability to do visual comparisons between the current model and a baseline (but not between two baselines). This includes added/changed/deleted model elements, as well as purely visual changes (moved elements) in diagrams.

You can use both Version Control and Baselines in the same EA project if you wish. My recommendation is always not to bother with Version Control at all and only use Baselines, but the best solution does depend on your specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

EA has a built-in feature Auditing. At first you need to enable it, then you can use some filters for the elements you only want to see the changes on. The history of elements will only be seen from the date you enabled this function.

http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/projects_and_teams/the_audit_view.html

CON: In case of a bigger database with many employees working on it it will generate ~1GB of data in a month.

Tamas